# replacing with a numbered value

Tags: regex, perl, powershell

suppose I have a string

```
$t = "some {great} vacation that {we} had that {year}"
```

and I want to replace the placeholders with a numbered value:

> "some {0} vacation that {1} had that {2}"

I'd have expected a single replacement to do it:

```
$i = 0; $t -replace "{.*?}", "{$([string] ++$i)}"
```

but what I get is:

> "some {1} vacation that {1} had that {1}"

as if the string is only evaluated once.  in perl regex there's a way to specify a function for the replacement value... how is this done in psh?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$i = 0 ; [Regex]::Matches($t,"{.*?}") | %{ ++$i ; $t = $t.Replace($_.Value,"{$i}") } ; $t
```

I think the problem is that the Regex engine never gets the new value of $i for each match it finds, so every time it increments it, `$i` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $t = "some {great} vacation that {we} had that {year}";
my $i = 0; 
$t =~ s!{.*?}!{$i++}!eg;
print $t;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/uhbmMD)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question --***“In Perl regex there's a way to specify a function for the replacement value. How is this done in psh?”***

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't figure out a way to do this using the `-replace` operator, so I had to resort to .net - here's a function that does it:

```
function nrep($s) {
    $script:i = 0
    $fn = {"[$([string] $script:i++)]"}
    [regex]::replace($s, '{.*?}', $fn)
}
```